# HighCharts speed o meter query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I am using highcharts speed o meter with PHP and MYSQL. It is working fine but the problem is that when I merge the JavaScript in my website, the speed o meter is not displaying. It does not appear any error, just blank screen where the speed o meter code is used. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {

$('#containers').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '100%'],
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Speed km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [<?php echo join($result, ',') ?>],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}, 
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {

    }
});
 });
```

I don't know what is problem if any one knows please tell me.

Comment: Blank chart usually means that your data is in an incorrect format, what does `<?php echo join($result, ',') ?>` produce?

Comment: <?php echo join($result, ',') ?> it gives the correct value from my database. Actually the problem is this code works in a separate file but it is combined with other codes speed o meter is not displaying

Comment: Well, what are these `other codes` you are referring to?  Here's a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/LWndm/1/ where I've cut and pasted the above and it works just fine.  Have you included `http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js`?

Comment: i am combining it with google maps used in my website

Comment: It is working fine in separate PHP file

Comment: I think you are missing the point here.  You've provided us a working code sample and then have asked, why isn't this working for me?  You haven't provided us anyway (or code) to know why it's broken, in your implementation, we can't just guess.

Comment: data: [<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: result in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test\map.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  join() [<a href='function.join'>function.join</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test\map.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
],

Comment: this warning is appearing in browser console

Comment: I advice to communicate your php with javacsirpt by json, see json_encode() option. In case when yor $report is undefined, try to print it above chart (as text in html) and check if this variable is printed.

Comment: @SebastianBochan $result is printed correctly and in page source it is also displayed in data but there is some problem it is not displaying when i merge it with other JS of Google maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing i see is that you forgot a semi-colon:

```
<?php echo join($result, ',') ?>
```

Change to

```
<?php echo join($result, ','); ?>
```

Otherwise try the console-debugger for the javascript-part.

Comment: i have changed the code but still it's not working. this code is working on separate file but when i merge the code it with other codes it is not working

Comment: Then logically the problem must be in the combination with the other files. setup `error_reporting(-1);` to check for unwanted collisions between the different files.

Comment: please tell me i am getting this warning and notice in browser console. data: [<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: result in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test\map.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: join() [<a href='function.join'>function.join</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\test\map.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br /> ],